# Como fazer um GridView desse jeito?

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá, eu estou aprendendo Android e eu aprendi bastante sobre ListView... Mas não muito sobre GridView, então eu gostaria de saber como desenvolver um GridView parecido com o abaixo: (O titulo "POPULAR" Não importa), só queria saber como configurar o "single item", pois tenho muitas dúvidas e creio que ao analisar o código posso resolver...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você vai ter que criar um adapter personalizado para carregar views customizadas. Dá uma pesquisada no Google. Tem milhares de tutoriais sobre isso.

Comment: Eu aconselharia você a fazer isso com um recyclerview
Indico este tutorial aqui:
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/